# Instantiate and use a user defined vba object using win32com

Tags: python, excel, com

I have a class module called CHouse in a workbook.

```
' Class CHouse
Public pAddress As String
Public pOwner As String
```

I want to create and use an object of this class, using win32com from Python. I could do this by writing a function that returns the object and run that macro using the Application.Run method on the Excel COM object.

Is there a more direct way to instantiate and use the above mentioned class? I assume that I would need to start the Excel instance and open the workbook to get at the class. Is there for example a method in the Excel object model that I can use to create the object? I am looking for something like how I can create a new Worksheet using the Sheets.Add method, or a new dictionary using win32com.client.Dispatch("Scripting.Dictionary").

I am using Python to access Excel in this way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more direct way to instantiate and use the above mentioned class? I assume that I would need to start the Excel instance and open the workbook to get at the class. Is there for example a method in the Excel object model that I can use to create the object?

The only possible way to run a VBA macro is to use the [Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run) method of the Excel `Application` class. You can create a new Excel instance and open the required workbook programmatically.

Comment: I am aware of this. I am trying to understand if I can instantiate an object without running a macro. For example, i can instantiate a new worksheet in my workbook, by using the Add method on the Sheets collection. Also, I can instantiate a dictionary using win32com.client.Dispatch("Scripting.Dictionary").

Comment: What object exactly do you want to instantiate?

Comment: See the updated post, for an example of a class module.

Comment: There is no way to instantiate VBA routines without the host application.

Comment: Does that mean I can if I use an Excel COM object then?

Comment: You can use the `Run` method to execute your VBA routine where such classes can be used.

Comment: Yeah. Thats the solution I already had and didn’t like…